# WebAPI CORS Policy when Creating new record

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I have a React frontend connecting to a .NET CORE WebAPI, I'm able to call, GET, Delete, and Create in one controller with no issues, however, on another controller, when I call the Create I get the CORS policy error message. What would cause the error in one controller and only the Create? I can call the Get and Delete with no issues, I can also call the Create from PostMan with no issues, just when I call it from my React App.

Create Code: (this works when I test it from Postman, I'm connecting to the API on my Local host for the time being, and only this one controller in the WebAPI is kicking me out the CORS policy error and only on the Create Call)

```
public IActionResult Create(CarDetails, details)
{
     db.CarDetails.Add(details);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return Ok(details.DetailsId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PostMan ignores CORS headers and will just not care about them. That is a reason for PostMan working while the browser does care.

With that said I do no really know why your API stops one request and not the other. Are there differences in the headers?

I think your problem would have a higher chance of getting solved when asked in a .NET forum. CORS errors are caused by settings for your backend/api host and not caused by React/JS/Client side code.

You might need to allow more headers, open up localhost:3000 or some other setting.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. once I added this to my API call file, it worked:

```
headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
```